# How do you run tests using a Capybara driver that require connecting to multiple databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, capybara

I am trying to run an acceptance test that uses the default Capybara driver to simulate user behavior on the web browser. The acceptance test I wrote requires a connection to an external database. When I run my acceptance test, I notice that it fails at the point where it should connect to the external database and retrieve the necessary information.

How do you set up Capybara to know about multiple database connections?

I read up on Jose Valim's solution to have Capybara know about your local database:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
   mattr_accessor :shared_connection
   @@shared_connection = nil

   def self.connection
     @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end

# Forces all threads to share the same connection. This works on
# Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

The problem with this approach is that it overrides all other database connections I have established (Here, I have another database connection FirstDatabase::Record that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base):

```
puts "First Record cxn: #{FirstDatabase::Record.connection}"
# => First Record cxn: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xe59b524>
puts "AR Base cxn: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection}"
# => AR Base cxn: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xc52761c>
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

puts "First Record cxn: #{FirstDatabase::Record.connection}"
# => First Record cxn: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xc52761c>
puts "AR Base cxn: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection}"
# => AR Base cxn: #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xc52761c>
```

As you can see, before I call the shared connection method, I have two different database connections. After, the shared connection method call, I have only one.

So any test that requires using the second database connection to retrieve information will fail. :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I can't run any of my capybara tests once I move to multiple databases.

Comment: @ksig No, I've moved on to a different project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem why Capybara tests need this hack is that database interactions are done in transactions so that the database can be cleaned out after the test finishes. And as the data is inserted into the database in an own transaction it cannot be seen by the browser.

I would suggest to turn off the transactions with something like

```
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

This should go to the environment.rb file, when I'm not wrong.

If the test is ok when run without transactions you can try out other options for cleaning up the database such as the [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). With the database cleaner you can then specify other cleaning options such as `:deletion` or `:truncation` (depending on which is faster with your tests).